# mod_rewrite dot in url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have problem in mod_rewrite the code

```
RewriteRule ^test-(.*)-(.*)$ s.php?$1 [R,L]
```

the url is work fine where link without dot like

test-1-something

but error will found if url is

test-1-something.html

please how can I fix it

thank's

**Edit:**
Error is 404 Not found

Comment: What error? Is it that difficult to copy-paste it?

Comment: Try removing the $ from the end and try again.

Comment: @Tushar Dhoot: for greedy `*` that `$` in the end changes nothing

Comment: @TusharDhoot I try it but it same error

Comment: @user533178: provide the whole `.htaccess` contents. And is it in the nested directory or in the site web root?

Comment: You perhaps dont need the `R` flag too.

Comment: @user533178: what if you remove everything except of `RewriteEngine On` and try the rule from the question again?

Comment: @zerkms I try it and same problem :(

Comment: you're rule is file, can you answer zerkms's question?